# Scraping with Simple HTML DOM Parser but it stops suddenly

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I'm trying to scrape the following page: http://mangafox.me/manga/

I wanted the script to click on each of those links and scrape the details of each manga and for the most part my code does exactly that. It works, but for some reason the page just stops loading midway (it doesn't even go through the # list).

There is no error message so I don't know what I'm looking for. I would appreciate some advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
    <?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

set_time_limit(0);

//ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
//Creates an instance of the simple_html_dom class
$html = new simple_html_dom();
//Loads the page from the URL entered
$html->load_file('http://mangafox.me/manga');
//Finds an element and if there is more than 1 instance the variable becomes an array
$manga_urls = $html->find('.manga_list a');


//Function which retrieves information needed to populate the DB from indiviual manga pages.
function getmanga($value, $url){ 
    $pagehtml = new simple_html_dom();
    $pagehtml->load_file($url);

    if ($value == 'desc') {
        $description = $pagehtml->find('p.summary');
        foreach($description as $d){
            //return $d->plaintext;
            return $desc = $d->plaintext;
        }
        unset($description);
    } else if ($value == 'status') {
        $status = $pagehtml->find('div[class=data] span');
        foreach ($status as $s) {
            $status = explode(",", $s->plaintext);
            return $status[0];
        }
        unset($status);
    } else if ($value == 'genre') {
        $genre = $pagehtml->find('//*[@id="title"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]');
        foreach ($genre as $g) {
            return $g->plaintext;
        }
        unset($genre);
    } else if ($value == 'author') {
        $author = $pagehtml->find('//*[@id="title"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]');
        foreach ($author as $a) {
            return $a->plaintext;
        }
        unset($author);
    } else if ($value == 'release') {
        $release = $pagehtml->find('//*[@id="title"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]');
        foreach ($release as $r) {
            return $r->plaintext;
        }
        unset($release);
    } else if ($value == 'image') {
        $image = $pagehtml->find('.cover img');
        foreach ($image as $i) {
            return $i->src;
        }
        unset($image);
    }

    $pagehtml->clear();
    unset($pagehtml);
} 

foreach($manga_urls as $url) {
    $href = $url->href;
    if (strpos($href, 'http') !== false){
        echo 'Title: ' . $url->plaintext . '<br />';
        echo 'Link: ' . $href . '<br />';
        echo 'Description: ' . getmanga('desc', $href) . '<br />';
        echo 'Status: ' . getmanga('status',$href) . '<br />';
        echo 'Genre: ' . getmanga('genre', $href) . '<br />';
        echo 'Author: ' . getmanga('author', $href) . '<br />';
        echo 'Release: ' . getmanga('release', $href) . '<br />';
        echo 'Image Link: ' . getmanga('image', $href) . '<br />';
        echo '<br /><br />';
    }
}

$html->clear();
unset($html);
?>
```

Comment: Show us the error report please.

Comment: Do you mean the error_log file? It doesn't have anything in it (apart from the previous errors I was getting from being an idiot E.g.

[30-Oct-2014 10:45:15 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home1/hashmkb/public_html/manga/simple_html_dom.php on line 1622

hence I put the set_time_limit(0); in the code.

Comment: Because I solved it by adding set_time_limit(0); Unless I've done it wrong :S

Comment: Also, you are using way too much requests! Keep in mind that every call to getmanga() fetches the page again and parses it again. My php was killed on a 2GB VPS because it was using too much memory!

Comment: Yeah your right, it has fixed the timeout, but still not the huge amount of memory you are allocating that leads to the crash :-)

Comment: How to I check the memory used and how can I fix it? From what you've said the first step would be to limit the request to getmanga() to just 1 per page but would that fix the memory issue and allow me to do all the pages?

Comment: I've rewritten getmanga() so I'm only making one call for each manga. Can't seem to paste the code in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was not a 'just do this' fix, but I did it ;)

Beside the fact is was importing the sub pages way too much, it also had a huge simple_html_dom to iterate through. It has like 13307 items, and simple_html_dom is not made for speed or efficiency. It allocated much space for things you didn't need in this case. That is why I replaced the main simple_html_dom with a regular expression.

I think it still takes ages to load fully, and you are better of using a other language, but this is a working result :-)
https://gist.github.com/dralletje/ee996ffe4c957cdccd01

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Michiel I wanted to understand what you did and try inserting into the database instead of echoing the values. Seems like the same issue happens but it lasts a lot longer. I think the best thing to do would be to parse a little bit at a time instead of the whole list in one go.

I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue, when the loop with 20k iterations stopped without any error message. So posting the solution so it might help someone.

The issue seems to be of performance as stated before. So I decided to use curl instead of simple html dom. The function bellow returns content of website:

```
function getContent($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($result){
        return $result;
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now to traverse the DOM, I am still using simple html dom, but the code is changed as:

```
$content = getContent($url);

if($content){
     // Create a DOM object
     $doc = new simple_html_dom();
     // Load HTML from a string
     $doc->load($content);
}else{
     continue;
}
```

And at the end of each loop close and unset variable as:

```
$doc->clear();
unset($doc);
```